# QNAP-NAS / git clone on NFS share not working

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, git, access-control-list, qnap

I'm using a QNAP NAS as storage server for my Ubuntu home directory. Everything seems to work fine, so far I did not encounter any problems with file permissions.
The output line of mount is:

```
192.168.0.200:/homes/myuser on /home/myuser type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.0.200,mountvers=3,mountport=30000,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.0.200)
```

However, when I try to clone a git repository into my home directory, I get the following output and error messages:

```
myuser@ubuntu ~/test % git clone -v https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git
Cloning into 'oh-my-zsh'...
POST git-upload-pack (140 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 17463, done.
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/home/myuser/test/oh-my-zsh/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
fatal: index-pack failed
```

After running the command, the directory test doesn't even contain a subdirectory named `oh-my-zsh`. It is still empty.

getfacl of the directory `/home/myuser/test/` shows the following output:

```
 myuser@ubuntu ~/test % getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: myuser
# group: mygroup
 user::rwx
 user:nobody:---
 user: myuser:rwx
 group::rwx
 mask::rwx
 other::---
 default:user::rwx
 default:user:nobody:---
 default:user: myuser:rwx
 default:group::rwx
 default:mask::rwx
 default:other::---
```

So actually there should be no permission problems, as myuser has all permissions on the directory. So is there something permission-related that I am missing? Or is this a NFS-related problem and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. I guess there's 2 ways.

1. Turn off Advanced ACL in QNAP-NAS. Go to Control Panel > Privilege > Shared Folders > Advanced Permissions > Uncheck [] Enable Advanced Folder Permissions

or

2. Add `noacl` option in `/etc/fstab` like follows. Options may differ depending on your preferences.

   `192.168.0.200:/homes/myuser /home/myuser nfs defaults,_netdev,noacl 1 2`

I did the latter and it worked.

Edit: If you want to keep using advanced ACL, make sure that NFSv4 is active on your NAS. [NFSv4 supports ACL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-nfs#s1-nfs-how), but NFSv3 probably not.

Edit: **I don't recommend the first way**. I tried it, and it resulted in a nightmare. All permissions were overwritten, folders 777, files 666. So you should leave the NAS option as it is now, and change client's NFS config only.

Comment: thank you, the `noacl` option worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem with git on an nfs mount from a QNAP. I had a different error message though:

```
Cloning into 'tileserver-gl'...
remote: Counting objects: 2179, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (813/813), done.
remote: Total 2179 (delta 1357), reused 2179 (delta 1357)
Receiving objects: 100% (2179/2179), 3.04 MiB | 22.72 MiB/s, done.
fatal: premature end of pack file, 83 bytes missing
warning: die() called many times. Recursion error or racy threaded death!
fatal: premature end of pack file, 81 bytes missing
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The fix was different of aximov's answer. The solution was adding the `sync` option to the mount options in `/etc/fstab`.

With that added the git clone works as expected.